# How can I know if a UDP packet got to the other side?

Tags: c#, networking

I can just reply to the sender, but the reply packet may not get to the other side too, which leaves me in an infinite loop...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: UDP is an unreliable protocol by design. I think your only option is to use TCP if you need to know whether a packet arrived or not.

Comment: Generally you can't. You need some sort of higher-level handling of tries and retries (and especially a *limit* to the number of retries). Most advanced protocols on top of UDP have implemented simple techniques mimicking TCP. If you want reliable communication without implementing your own TCP-like protocol on top of UDP, you might want to actually consider TCP.

Comment: You, alone, can never be sure. There must be some mechanism in the system that can answer your UDP package so that you have the confirmation that it has been received. But it starts to look like TCP. Maybe your should change the protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is off topic, and there's tons of information on this on the internet.

What I would do is reply to the sender with an "OK", passing a packetId with it so that the sender knows to which packet he receives an OK. If the sender does not get an OK within 30 seconds (or whatever) he sends the package again (with the same packageID). The retriever handles the package again, unless he already got it. In both cases he will send an OK package to the sender. So the sender does not know whether or not his message went wrong, or whether the retrievers message went wrong. It really doesn't matter too, if you use packageIds.

BTW, UDP is a protocol that typically does not promise for a package to get to its destination. So if you do want to guarantee this, you should probably just use a different protocol (i.e. TCP).

Comment: `they pretty much always do` this totally depends on your scenario and infrastructure.

Comment: Ill edit my answer to satisfy your point, because you're right. What I'm trying to convey is that even though UDP does not promise a guaranteed ride, it doesn't mean that that always happens (something that one might believe after reading about UDP for the first time).